# Incremental processing in an akka actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have actors that need to do very long-running and computationally expensive work, but the computation itself can be done incrementally. So while the complete computation itself takes hours to complete, the intermediate results are actually extremely useful, and I'd like to be able to respond to any requests of them. This is the pseudo code of what I want to do:

```
var intermediateResult = ...
loop {
     while (mailbox.isEmpty && computationNotFinished)
       intermediateResult = computationStep(intermediateResult)


     receive {
         case GetCurrentResult => sender ! intermediateResult
         ...other messages...
     }
 }
```

Comment: That's interesting. Maybe one method would be to have a child actor continue to calculate the steps and on each step it sends the updated computation data to the parent. Then when GetCurrentResult is sent to the parent actor, it won't interfere with any computation steps or anything. I always find it a dangerous thought when I am wondering what the current mailbox size is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume from your comment to Roland Kuhn answer that you have some work which can be considered as recursive, at least in blocks. If this is not the case, I don't think there could be any clean solution to handle your problem and you will have to deal with complicated pattern matching blocks.

If my assumptions are correct, I would schedule the computation asynchronously and let the actor be free to answer other messages. The key point is to use Future monadic capabilities and having a simple receive block. You would have to handle three messages (startComputation, changeState, getState)

You will end up having the following receive:

```
def receive {
  case StartComputation(myData) =>expensiveStuff(myData)
  case ChangeState(newstate) = this.state = newstate
  case GetState => sender ! this.state
}
```

And then you can leverage the map method on Future, by defining your own recursive map:

```
 def mapRecursive[A](f:Future[A], handler: A => A, exitConditions: A => Boolean):Future[A] = {
    f.flatMap {  a=>
                 if (exitConditions(a))
                   f
                 else {
                     val newFuture = f.flatMap{ a=> Future(handler(a))}
                     mapRecursive(newFuture,handler,exitConditions)
                 }

              }
  }
```

Once you have this tool, everything is easier. If you look to the following example :

```
def main(args:Array[String]){
    val baseFuture:Future[Int] = Promise.successful(64)
    val newFuture:Future[Int] = mapRecursive(baseFuture,
                                 (a:Int) => {
                                   val result = a/2
                                   println("Additional step done: the current a is " + result)
                                   result
                                 }, (a:Int) => (a<=1))

    val one = Await.result(newFuture,Duration.Inf)
    println("Computation finished, result = " + one)



  }
```

Its output is:

> Additional step done: the current a is 32
>
> Additional step done: the current a is 16
>
> Additional step done: the current a is 8
>
> Additional step done: the current a is 4
>
> Additional step done: the current a is 2
>
> Additional step done: the current a is 1
>
> Computation finished, result = 1

You understand you can do the same, inside your `expensiveStuff`method

```
  def expensiveStuff(myData:MyData):Future[MyData]= {
    val firstResult = Promise.successful(myData)
    val handler : MyData => MyData = (myData) => {
      val result = myData.copy(myData.value/2)
      self ! ChangeState(result)
      result
    }
    val exitCondition : MyData => Boolean = (myData:MyData) => myData.value==1
    mapRecursive(firstResult,handler,exitCondition)
  }
```

---

**EDIT - MORE DETAILED**

If you don't want to block the Actor, which processes messages from its mailbox in a thread-safe and synchronous manner, the only thing you can do is to get the computation executed on a different thread. This is exactly an high performance non blocking receive.

However, you were right in saying that the approach I propose pays a high performance penalty. Every step is done on a different future, which might be not necessary at all. You can therefore recurse the handler to obtain a single-threaded or multiple-threaded execution. There is no magic formula after all:

- If you want to schedule asynchronously and minimize the cost, all the work should be done by a single thread
- This however could prevent other work to start, because if all the threads on a thread pool are taken, the futures will queue. You might therefore want to break the operation into multiple futures so that even at full usage some new work can be scheduled before old work has been completed.

---

```
def recurseFuture[A](entryFuture: Future[A], handler: A => A, exitCondition: A => Boolean, maxNestedRecursion: Long = Long.MaxValue): Future[A] = {
        def recurse(a:A, handler: A => A, exitCondition: A => Boolean, maxNestedRecursion: Long, currentStep: Long): Future[A] = {
          if (exitCondition(a))
            Promise.successful(a)
          else
            if (currentStep==maxNestedRecursion)
              Promise.successful(handler(a)).flatMap(a => recurse(a,handler,exitCondition,maxNestedRecursion,0))
            else{
              recurse(handler(a),handler,exitCondition,maxNestedRecursion,currentStep+1)
            }
        }
        entryFuture.flatMap { a => recurse(a,handler,exitCondition,maxNestedRecursion,0) }
      }
```

I have enhanced for testing purposes my handler method:

```
  val handler: Int => Int = (a: Int) => {
      val result = a / 2
      println("Additional step done: the current a is " + result + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName)
      result
    }
```

*Approach 1: Recurse the handler on itself so to get all execute on a single thread.*

```
    println("Starting strategy with all the steps on the same thread")
    val deepestRecursion: Future[Int] = recurseFuture(baseFuture,handler, exitCondition)
    Await.result(deepestRecursion, Duration.Inf)
    println("Completed strategy with all the steps on the same thread")
    println("")
```

*Approach 2: Recurse for a limited depth the handler on itself*

```
println("Starting strategy with the steps grouped by three")
val threeStepsInSameFuture: Future[Int] = recurseFuture(baseFuture,handler, exitCondition,3)
val threeStepsInSameFuture2: Future[Int] = recurseFuture(baseFuture,handler, exitCondition,4)
Await.result(threeStepsInSameFuture, Duration.Inf)
Await.result(threeStepsInSameFuture2, Duration.Inf)
println("Completed strategy with all the steps grouped by three")
executorService.shutdown()
```

Comment: This is looking very nice, and your assumptions are indeed correct. I'll use this / pick this as the answer if no better solutions comes along. My big concern however is just performance related, as my steps are rather fine-grained and often (Each actor will need to do, quite literally millions before the computation is done). I really do wish there was some sort of high-performance non-blocking receive

Comment: Enhanced answer...look if it helps

Comment: Using Futures introduces an extra overhead, not only for their management but also for sending the data to different CPUs. My solution is rather similar to a while loop, just one call stack above the receive (i.e. this while loop is literally in the Akka code which runs the actor’s mailbox) and it can run ca 3 million msgs/sec for one actor on my notebook. I don't know why this does not qualify as high-performance to you.

Comment: Your solution is definitely most performing then mine, but the actor loop would deal with the calculation and would not be able to answer to external "state request", so it would not satisfy the requirements

Answer (score 8):

The best way to do this is very close to what you are doing already:

```
case class Continue(todo: ToDo)
class Worker extends Actor {
  var state: IntermediateState = _
  def receive = {
    case Work(x) =>
      val (next, todo) = calc(state, x)
      state = next
      self ! Continue(todo)
    case Continue(todo) if todo.isEmpty => // done
    case Continue(todo) =>
      val (next, rest) = calc(state, todo)
      state = next
      self ! Continue(rest)
  }
  def calc(state: IntermediateState, todo: ToDo): (IntermediateState, ToDo)
}
```

### EDIT: more background

When an actor sends messages to itself, Akka’s internal processing will basically run those within a `while` loop; the number of messages processed in one go is determined by the actor’s dispatcher’s `throughput` setting (defaults to 5), after this amount of processing the thread will be returned to the pool and the continuation be enqueued to the dispatcher as a new task. Hence there are two tunables in the above solution:

- process multiple steps for a single message (if processing steps are REALLY small)
- increase `throughput` setting for increased throughput and decreased fairness

The original problem seems to have hundreds of such actors running, presumably on common hardware which does not have hundreds of CPUs, so the throughput setting should probably be set such that each batch takes no longer than ca. 10ms.

### Performance Assessment

Let’s play a bit with Fibonacci:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-RC1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_07).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def fib(x1: BigInt, x2: BigInt, steps: Int): (BigInt, BigInt) = if(steps>0) fib(x2, x1+x2, steps-1) else (x1, x2)
fib: (x1: BigInt, x2: BigInt, steps: Int)(BigInt, BigInt)

scala> def time(code: =>Unit) { val start = System.currentTimeMillis; code; println("code took " + (System.currentTimeMillis - start) + "ms") }
time: (code: => Unit)Unit

scala> time(fib(1, 1, 1000))
code took 1ms

scala> time(fib(1, 1, 1000))
code took 1ms

scala> time(fib(1, 1, 10000))
code took 5ms

scala> time(fib(1, 1, 100000))
code took 455ms

scala> time(fib(1, 1, 1000000))
code took 17172ms
```

Which means that in a presumably quite optimized loop, fib_100000 takes half a second. Now let’s play a bit with actors:

```
scala> case class Cont(steps: Int, batch: Int)
defined class Cont

scala> val me = inbox()
me: akka.actor.ActorDSL.Inbox = akka.actor.dsl.Inbox$Inbox@32c0fe13

scala> val a = actor(new Act {
  var s: (BigInt, BigInt) = _
  become {
    case Cont(x, y) if y < 0 => s = (1, 1); self ! Cont(x, -y)
    case Cont(x, y) if x > 0 => s = fib(s._1, s._2, y); self ! Cont(x - 1, y)
    case _: Cont => me.receiver ! s
   }
})
a: akka.actor.ActorRef = Actor[akka://repl/user/$c]

scala> time{a ! Cont(1000, -1); me.receive(10 seconds)}
code took 4ms

scala> time{a ! Cont(10000, -1); me.receive(10 seconds)}
code took 27ms

scala> time{a ! Cont(100000, -1); me.receive(10 seconds)}
code took 632ms

scala> time{a ! Cont(1000000, -1); me.receive(30 seconds)}
code took 17936ms
```

This is already interesting: given long enough time per step (with the huge BigInts behind the scenes in the last line), actors don’t much extra. Now let’s see what happens when doing smaller calculations in a more batched way:

```
scala> time{a ! Cont(10000, -10); me.receive(30 seconds)}
code took 462ms
```

This is pretty close to the result for the direct variant above.

### Conclusion

Sending messages to self is NOT expensive for almost all applications, just keep the actual processing step slightly larger than a few hundred nanoseconds.

Comment: I'm doing some serious work and there's hundreds of actors with millions of step (i'm doing SGD). If they all have to march to a beat of an async drum, that's really going to kill slow them down hugely

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that drum metaphor: my code will do quite exactly what you want. If each single calculation step is too small and the dispatch overhead too large then just run 1000 of them in one go. Also play with the throughput setting of the dispatcher.

Comment: Edited to add the performance assessment; please note that I did not even touch the throughput setting, the numbers are with the default value of 5.

Comment: Your benchmarks have convinced me, and I'll take your approach. I'll just try make each step something like 100 steps or something. I'll award this the bounty when it allows me to

Comment: Thanks! Let me know how it works out in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: What about putting this in the wiki?

Comment: which wiki are you refering to?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use Actors to make long running computations as these will block the threads that are supposed to run the Actors code.

I would try to go with a design that uses a separate Thread/ThreadPool for the computations and use AtomicReferences to store/query the intermediate results in the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
val cancelled = new AtomicBoolean(false)
val intermediateResult = new AtomicReference[IntermediateResult]()

object WorkerThread extends Thread {
  override def run {
    while(!cancelled.get) {
      intermediateResult.set(computationStep(intermediateResult.get))
    }
  }
}

loop {
  react {
    case StartComputation => WorkerThread.start()
    case CancelComputation => cancelled.set(true)
    case GetCurrentResult => sender ! intermediateResult.get
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic concurrency problem. You want want several routines/actors (or whatever you want to call them). Code is mostly correct Go, with obscenely long variable names for context. The first routine handles queries and intermediate results:

```
func serveIntermediateResults(
        computationChannel chan *IntermediateResult,
        queryChannel chan chan<-*IntermediateResult) {
    var latestIntermediateResult *IntermediateResult // initial result
    for {
        select {
        // an update arrives
        case latestIntermediateResult, notClosed := <-computationChannel:
            if !notClosed {
                // the computation has finished, stop checking
                computationChannel = nil
            }
        // a query arrived
        case queryResponseChannel, notClosed := <-queryChannel:
            if !notClosed {
                // no more queries, so we're done
                return
            }
            // respond with the latest result
            queryResponseChannel<-latestIntermediateResult
        }
    }
}
```

In your long computation, you update your intermediate result wherever appropriate:

```
func longComputation(intermediateResultChannel chan *IntermediateResult) {
    for notFinished {
        // lots of stuff
        intermediateResultChannel<-currentResult
    }
    close(intermediateResultChannel)
}
```

Finally to ask for the current result, you have a wrapper to make this nice:

```
func getCurrentResult() *IntermediateResult {
     responseChannel := make(chan *IntermediateResult)
     // queryChannel was given to the intermediate result server routine earlier
     queryChannel<-responseChannel
     return <-responseChannel
}
```