# The actor pattern with Akka and long running processes

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

Lately I have been investigating the awesome Akka framework to try to get a feel for it and decide if it would be right for my project. Currently this application is a plain old java application that performs some very complex calculations by making calls to various external c++ executable's (sometimes the calculations can take hours to run). In code it would look something like this

```
public static class Worker extends UntypedActor {
  // Run Very Long Process 
  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message instanceof Work) {
        Work work = (Work) message;
        double result = veryLongProcess(work.getStart(),work.getNrOfElements());
        getSender().tell(new Result(result), getSelf());
    } else {
       unhandled(message);
    }
  }
}
```

My question is can Akka handle actors taking sometimes hours to return from their execution?

Comment: You can configure the dispatcher to be the appropriate thread model for your application. You probably want to setup a separate thread pool for the dispatcher that is running slow tasks and leave the default dispatcher for other actors doing short lived tasks. http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html it's a good idea to read all the docs when coming to such a rich framework to get awareness of all the configurable parts.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I guess my concern is that Akka has some sort of timeout or some other such feature that after a certain amount of elapsed time would assume the actor has died.

Comment: In my experience the work just tanks up in the actor mailboxes until you run out of heap or threads. So resource management is something you have to design in else configure. Simple things are simple, complex things are possible. My top tip is don't make everything an actor. Futures are also your friend and use only actors to make multitasking and remoting easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question directly; there is a [good article](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html) on this very topic:

> Again, if you have long-running computations, having them run in a
>   separate ExecutionContext for CPU-bound tasks is a good idea.

The article has the following example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import concurrent.ExecutionContext

//I added 'private' for the rest of the example
private val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
private val executionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executorService)
```

Answering indirectly,

**Futures First**

I completely agree that Akka Actors are a very useful tool for particular types of work.  When it comes to caching, `Actors` & `Agents` are the best game in town.

However, in this instance I would suggest leveraging a `Future` instead of an Actor.  You could make veryLongProcess a `private` function.  The privacy would allow complete control over the number of threads calling the method at once:

```
def longProcessFut(start : Int, noOfElements : Int) : Future[Result] = Future {
  veryLongProcess(start, noOfElements)
}(executionContext)//controls the executing pool of veryLongProcess
```

Simple, concise, and asynchronous.

No killing of letters, no overloaded receive method that accepts anything under the sun, nor Props, not even an ActorRef was necessary for the Future.  Bloat, beer belly I say!

Besides, your user is going to create a Future no matter what because of `?`:

```
//Actor user code, too verbose

val longProcessRef = actorSystem actorOf Props[Worker]

val fut : Future[Result] = (longProcessRef ? Work(0,42)).mapTo[Result]
```

Compared to using Futures directly

```
//happy user code

val fut : Future[Result] = longProcessFut(0, 42)
```

Same great Future, but half the calories!

You can control the dispatcher of the Future in the same manner(s) as suggested in the comments, which are quite good.  You can even use `actorSystem.dispatcher` as your Future dispatcher to control the dispatcher behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome and thorough response! My one remaining question would be can you still have access to the remoting module of Akka with the use of Futures? We will be having a high load of traffic on the system and the goal is to be able to spread out these computations across n number of machines.

Comment: I am unaware of any functionality for running Futures remotely, so Actors still have that advantage.  However, when I am personally doing distributed computation I use Apache Spark or Akka Streams (not Actors directly).

Answer (score 1):

If the long running business logic / algorithm is incremental, produces intermediate results and/or can run for a *very* long time then you may want to reuse excellent design snippets from here: [Incremental processing in an akka actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851996/incremental-processing-in-an-akka-actor)